# plotly - changing the line styles

Tags: python, plot, plotly, roc

I am trying to plot multiple yet related things on a plotly graph.

I want to differentiate and relate the lines at the same time. To make myself more clearer, I am plotting ROC characteristics of the classifiers that I trained. I want a particular classifier of the same color but different line styles for the method of training.

I currently use this to fulfill my requirement:
[image]

Here is the code for the same,

```
    data = [
        go.Scatter(
            mode='lines+markers',
            x=df_LogisticRegression['FPR'], # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
            y=df_LogisticRegression['TPR'],
            name = "Logistic Regression all attributes",
            marker=dict(
                color="blue",
                symbol='square'
            ),
        ),
        # and so on for all other algos
        go.Scatter(
            mode='lines+markers',
            x=df_LogisticRegression_nonSP['FPR'], # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
            y=df_LogisticRegression_nonSP['TPR'],
            name = "Logistic Regression non-sparse attributes",
            marker=dict(
                color="blue",
                symbol='square-open'
            ),
        ),
         # and so on for all other algos
    ]
layout = go.Layout(
    title='ROC Curve',
    yaxis=dict(title='True Positive Rates(TPR)'),
    xaxis=dict(title='False Positive Rates(FPR)')
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

For instance,
I am looking to have the color of logistic regression as blue, but the one with "all attributes should be a solid line and the one with "non-sparse attributes" should be broken lines.

I tried to look up and read up the documentation for plotly but could not find anything help.

Comment: when you write `lines` in mode it is going to plot the lines even if the points are sparse. it will join the points.

Comment: just try `mode=markers` for the non-sparse dataset

Comment: I need a line, can I not change the line style in any way? I am looking at [Plotly shapes](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/) and the first example in it, is there a similar thing I can achieve?

Comment: Yes, to plot a line just say `mode=lines`

Comment: I found the solution on [Plotly line graphs](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/). Thank you. A Eureka moment for me! :)

Comment: Please update the question with details of solution and close the question so that the wider community knows that the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the plotly, plots the data based on the mode which you ask it to do. If you say `mode=markers` it is going to plot just the markers. If you say `mode=lines` it is going the join all the points in the data and plot it as lines.

Please see this page https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#line-and-scatter-plots for more examples of lines that can be plotted using plotly.